# listing words that follow a word along with their frequency in a text file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

Is there a clean way to get a list of words that follow a particular pattern in a text file, along with their frequencies using `grep`, `sed`, or `awk`? For example, assume the following text file:

```
155 20 120 156 20 9 157 158 9 40
163 7 95 164 20 9 165 9 40
99 100 20 15 29 101 6 9 40 165
9 22 23 167 168 9 165 171 40
```

I want to know what are the words that follow 9, and the number of times they occur next to 9. So, the output looks like this:

```
157 1
40  3
165 2
22  1
```

Comment: @PrerakSola java programmed it!

Comment: Can you please show it. And what is the error/non-required behavior ?

Comment: It's a working program. But it's always good to have a one line solution.

Comment: You should have included cases where there are consecutive `9`s and a `9` at the end of a line in your sample input/output. It's always worth putting effort into figuring out as many test cases as you can imagine that might be hard for a script to handle and/or have non-obvious output requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
grep -owE "9 [0-9]+" filename | sed "s/^9 //" | sort -n | uniq -c
```

It returns nearly what you want:

```
  1 22
  3 40
  1 157
  2 165
```

*Limitation: consecutive `9` digits are not counted with this method.*

Comment: Very nice. With GNU grep, we can take advantage of perl-compatible regexes and can avoid calling sed: `grep -oP '\b9\s+\K\d+' | sort ...`

Comment: @glenn jackman: even better! that's a precious suggestion. thanks a lot.

Comment: That will fail to count the "word" that follows a second `9`. Try it with `9 9 3` as the input and you'll find that `3` doesn't get counted.

Comment: @Ed Morton: thanks for the note. I've added the limitation in the answer.

Comment: You could also just add a look ahead pattern to capture the consecutive `9`'s. Here is the new pattern that will count consecutive `9`'s: `grep -owE "(?)9 [0-9]+" filename | sed "s/^9 //" | sort -n | uniq -c`

Comment: @cr1msonB1ade: Are you sure the same command worked for you? I tried it using *three* grep versions: GNU grep 2.21, 2.5.1 and 2.63 and all reported: `grep: Unmatched ) or \)`. It looks like `grep -E` mode simply lacks the lookahead regex capability. Using `grep -P` *(perl mode)* didn't help. Would you please double check?

Comment: It works for me using 2.5.1-FreeBSD grep, but actually doesn't perform the correct look ahead on a second look. Sorry for that suggestion as it does not work. I also tried it on GNU grep 2.16 and I get the same error as you. It looks like the look ahead is possible though with a perl regex: `grep -oP "(?<=9) [0-9]+" foo.txt | sort -n | uniq -c`

Answer (score 4):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS='\\s+' 'p==9{c[$0]++} {p=$0} END{for (w in c) print w, c[w]}' file
165 2
157 1
22 1
40 3
```

With other awks:

```
$ awk '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) if ($(i-1)==9) c[$i]++} END{for (w in c) print w, c[w]}' file
165 2
157 1
22 1
40 3
```

Answer (score 2):

With awk, you can write:

```
awk '
    {
        for (i=1; i<NF; i++) 
            if ($i == 9) 
                follow[$(++i)]++
    } 
    END {
        for (f in follow) 
            print f, follow[f]
    }
' file
```

```
22 1
40 3
157 1
165 2
```

Comment: I'm not sure you want `follow[$(++i)]++` vs `follow[$(i+1)]++` as the former will skip a field and that field might be a `9` (missing requirement from OP - how to handle consecutive 9s).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an awk only solution:

```
awk '{for(i=1; i < NF; i++){
      if($i == 9) nextToNine[$(i+1)]++;}} 
      END{for(j in nextToNine) print j"\t"nextToNine[j]}' test.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl regex with `grep`:

```
grep -oP "(?<=\b9\s)\d+" file |sort -n|uniq -c
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl only solution:

```
perl -ne '$h{$1}++ while /\b9 (\w+)/g }{ print "$_ $h{$_}\n" for keys %h' input.txt
```